# Woocommerce product listing design issues

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic

In my design the every product is listing like

```
<div class="col-md-3 special-products-grid text-center">
                        <a class="brand-name" href="single-page.html"><img src="images/b2.jpg" title="name" /></a>
                        <a class="product-here" href="single-page.html"><img src="images/p2.jpg" title="product-name" /></a>
                        <h4><a href="single-page.html">Line Link 67009</a></h4>
                        <a class="product-btn" href="single-page.html"><span>109.90$</span><small>GET NOW</small><label> </label></a>
                    </div>
```

while in woocommerce plugin the product is listing in ul and li fashion how i fixed this issue because i have set the css on div while in woocommerce shop page it listing in ul.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nasir, you can inherit the woo-commerce template files into your current theme and integrate your html, here you can find the woo theme Integration guide http://docs.woothemes.com/documentation/plugins/woocommerce/woocommerce-codex/theming/

Comment: can i itegrate my html in which file.

Comment: for integration of listing you need to inherit **archive-product.php** which is located in **/plugins/woocommerce/templates**. :)

Comment: can you please guide me step by step i am beginner.

Comment: It's not possible friend, instead you can google, there are many videos for beginners..anyway you can look into this, it may help you a lot [link](http://code.tutsplus.com/articles/an-introduction-to-theming-woocommerce-for-wordpress--wp-31577)